# Composer packages update but don't install

Tags: package, composer-php

After doing

`sudo php composer.phar update`

I get the following:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information 
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Installing SOME_PACKAGE (dev-master 6fb0f62)
Cloning SOME_TOKEN
Writing lock file Generating autoload filesUpdating
```

But when I do `sudo php composer.phar install` I get

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
```

Does someone have any idea on what might be happening? I have a `composer.json, composer.phar and composer.lock` all in the same folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong in your opinion? With `composer update`, composer tries to find new versions of the packages within the specified version range. When found, it updates the package. At the end, it creates a `composer.lock` file with all packages and details about the installed versions.

`composer install` only reads this `composer.lock` file and installs exactly the versions specified in this. Since you already have the versions specified in that lock file, nothing will happen.

`composer install` is very usefull on production servers and in teams, as you'll be sure you all are using exact the same version of the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Check if composer.look is using a package that uses an extension not released in php.ini . After releasing the extensions use comoser install

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).