# Composer install error after update to Cakephp 3.0.6

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I just run `composer update` and Cakephp was updated to `3.0.6` version so after that when I'm trying to run `composer install` I'm getting this error:

```
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Script App\Console\Installer::postInstall handling the post-install-cmd event te
rminated with an exception



  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Maximum number of attempts must be a positive value.
```

Comment: Check [this issue](https://github.com/cakephp/app/issues/241) and apply the commit made by lorenzo. that fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a probably duplicate of [Composer packages update but don't install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28394785/composer-packages-update-but-dont-install)

Composer updated the CakePHP version with the update. Nothing to install. So, you should be good, as long as there were no app-breaking changes for you in 3.0.6. https://adamcod.es/2013/03/07/composer-install-vs-composer-update.html tells how to lock your set-up so that you don't accidentally upgrade versions when you're not expecting it.